# Add custom property to standard control

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

Being a bit lazy, I'd like to add some properties of mine to a control, WITHOUT the hassle of creating a custom control.

Say there is a Button control, I'd like to add a secondary Tag property to it.

Or a textbox I want an oldText property for it...

I do not need the added properties to show in the properties window. I just need to use them in code.

Any idea?

Please do NOT answer if telling me I HAVE to use custom control or derived class. I need the ease of use of standard controls from the toolbar.

On the other hand, something like Partial Class would do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best answer is the one that I think you're not allowing us to give - that is, use inheritance to create an inherited control.

However, you might be able to make a work-around using an [`IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Inherited controls are fine, what I do not want is a user control... Your answer is fine, thanks. I have also found same details in StackOverflow here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364961/windows-forms-how-to-extend-a-button)

Answer (score 3):

**For WPF**

Extend from Button and add the desired [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). You don't have to create a custom user control from scratch.

You could also use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to add additional functionality without using inheritance.

**For winforms**

My winforms is a little bit rusty, but I notice you can also [simply extend from Button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3364961/590790).

Comment: Well... Your answer fits for WPF development... I'm sorry to say that I'm using Winforms! Maybe I should have stated it in the question.

Comment: @user512602: you can still simply [extend from Button](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3364961/590790).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to extend the class and you just want to reference the "properties" in code, you could consider building a `Dictionary<T, V>`, where `T` is the type of control, and `V` is the type you wish to map to the control. It could be a string or a custom type, in the case of wanting to have multiple properties mapped to the same control.

Maybe you have

```
class CustomPropertyBag
{
    public string OldText { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    // more
}
```

You could have `Dictionary<TextBox, CustomPropertyBag> dictionary` in your code, which would allow you to map your custom properties and textboxes together.

```
dictionary[textBox1].OldText = "whatever";
```